# How to return item from multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text file with contents such as following which are ids and names.

```
23414,apple
24323,orange
64563,banana
```

In a PHP file I read in the content of the text file into an array like

```
$itemArray = array();

$records = file('/path/to.file/guilds.txt');
foreach ($records as $line) {
$lineArray = explode(',',$line);
array_push($itemArray,$lineArray);  
}
```

If I know the id of a particular record say 24323, how can I return the associated name, orange. All ids are unique. I tried something like the following with no luck.

```
$id = 24323;

echo "Result:" . array_search($id, array_column($itemArray,1,0));
```

Edit: To clarify code.

Comment: you can achieve the goal with 2 lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I know the id of a particular record say 2, how can I return the
>   associated name, orange. All ids are unique. I tried something like
>   the following with no luck.

Since you said ids are unique, better you create array like below,

```
$itemArray = array();

$records = file('/path/to.file/guilds.txt');
foreach ($records as $line) 
{
    $lineArray = explode(',',$line);
    $itemArray[ $lineArray[0] ] = $lineArray;  

   /* Use below if you just want to store name 
      $itemArray[ $lineArray[0] ] = $lineArray[0];  
   */
}
```

and you can access them easily like below

```
$id = 24323;
print_r( $itemArray[$id] );

/*You will get below
          Array
          (
            [0] => 24323
            [1] => orange
           )

*/

// and if you want just to print orange then
echo $itemArray[$id][1];   // orange
```

Comment: Why not `$itemArray[ $lineArray[0] ] = $lineArray[1];`?

Comment: @Aydin: see op has edited look at his ids, and OP hasn't made clear so I stored entire array instead of just one element

Comment: Why not store $itemArray as `(23414=>'apple', 24323=>'orange', ...)` ? And retrieve it with `$itemArray[24323];`(will produce 'orange').

Comment: @Aydin: please see my edit, you can store, I had put it in comment let OP select whichever he/she want

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this, when the text file was read, exploded and pushed into array, each was treated as an individual element of the array which results in array structure like:

```
$itemArray[0] => 1
$itemArray[1] => Apple
$itemArray[2] => 2
$itemArray[3] => Orange
$itemArray[4] => 3
$itemArray[5] => banana
```

So I think you should read with index

Answer (score 0):

Short `preg_match_all` + `array_combine` functions solution:

```
preg_match_all('/^(?P<id>[0-9]+),(?P<name>\w+)\s*/m', file_get_contents('/path/to.file/guilds.txt'), $m);
$result = array_combine($m['id'], $m['name']);

print_r($result[24323]);
```

The output:

```
orange
```